# ORDER_BY date LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have table named notify with (seeker, donor, date) columns 
the date column of type (datetime) and it stores the following format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS 
 I'm trying to SELECT 1 record with the latest date from notify table and then compare the date with the current date and calculate the number of days between tow dates..

```
<?php

session_start();
$email = $_GET['email'];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh');
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$note = "SELECT * FROM notify WHERE seeker='".$_SESSION['email']."'AND donor='".$email."' ORDER_BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1";
$st = $conn->prepare($note);
$st->execute();

if($found = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $now = $time;
    $old_date = strtotime($found['date']);
    $dateif = $now - $old_date;

    if(floor($dateif/(60*60*24)) >= 7){
    echo "the difference between tow dates is 7 days or more";
    } else { echo "difference between tow dates is less than 7 days";}
}
?>
```

the code is not working ! 
 i have only one record in my notify table with this value in date 2013-04-22 09:15:47

Comment: are date and time table column?

Comment: `ORDER_BY date, time` should be at the end of the query - not in the middle

Comment: no, i have only one column (time) that store $time value

Comment: @ibobo: How is your table structured?

Comment: @ibobo You should store date times in a DATETIME field. That is properly sortable. A string like `Tue 23, Apr 2013 07:44:14` is not sortable on its date value.

Comment: @Arjan what i understand is i have to make one column called "datetime" in my user table and stor the date and time together in that column.. right ?

Comment: Not exactly. The column name is free to choose, the column type should be [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @Arjan now i have column called 'time' with type 'datetime' and i stored value in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS',,, what method are appropriate to pick up one record with latest date and time ?

Comment: You're not using prepared statements correctly.

Comment: @Jack why ? what is wrong with my prepare statement ?

Comment: It's explained in my answer.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. I hope that you intentionally removed database connection code before posting here and make sure that data exists in DB for $_SESSION['email'] & $email.

Comment: @monish it is exist in DB </3 i dunno what i should do

Comment: Please do not post the same question again. If you have more details to add, edit your previous question.

Comment: About the SQL, I strongly advice to read some tutorials on internet, including [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should use prepared statements like this:

```
$note = "SELECT * 
    FROM notify 
    WHERE seeker=:seeker AND donor=:donor 
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT 1";

$st = $conn->prepare($note);
$st->execute(array(
    ':seeker' => $_SESSION['email'],
    ':donor' => $email,
);
```

*Without the place holders you're still open to SQL injection.*

Second, you can't compare a string with an integer in this way:

```
$now = $time; // string
$old_date = strtotime($found['date']); // integer
$dateif = $now - $old_date; // dunno?
```

You should compare apples with apples:

```
$seven_days_ago = strtotime('-7 days');
$old_date = strtotime($found['date']);

if ($old_date > $seven_days_ago) {
    echo "difference between tow dates is less than 7 days";
} else {
    echo "the difference between tow dates is 7 days or more";
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to compare (7 days ago) with old date!!

i wanna compare the current date with $old_date from database

Comment: @ibobo This is comparing current date with `$old_date`; I've just merged it with the `>= 7` condition you already had.

Comment: does the result of strtotime('-7 days'); equal to current date time ??

Comment: @ibobo No, it does not; but your code continues to test whether `$old_date` is older than 7 days or not ... that's what my code does as well, but in a different way.

Comment: Still not working, i tried your code .. no result
what i guess is the problem in the QUERY not the comparison 
cuz i tried only to echo the $found['date']; after executing the query and it is not printed

Comment: @ibobo `ORDER BY` does not have an underscore in it.

Comment: @ibobo Should be fixed, I didn't realize you had a typo in your original query.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `date` column doesn't exist, there's no point in ordering by it. Also, you're exposed to SQL injection in the case where `$_SESSION['email']` is not secured.

So, the correct form would be to use prepared statements, as well as order by the right column. (assuming PDO, you can use mysqli as well):

```
/** @var PDO $pdo - Assuming a PDO connection. */
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `ID` = :email ORDER BY `time` DESC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['email']));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Get all results in an associated array form.
```

Answer (score 1):

Jack's answer shows you how to use prepared statements correctly. Here is the code to simplify the date calculation using `DATEDIFF()`.

```
$note = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), `date`) AS date_diff
         FROM notify 
         WHERE seeker=:seeker AND donor=:donor
         ORDER_BY `date` DESC
         LIMIT 1";

$st = $conn->prepare($note);
$st->execute(array(
    ':seeker' => $_SESSION['email'],
    ':donor' => $email,
);

$row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// do something with $row
```

Comment: That wouldn't give any results for older than 7 days.

Comment: @Jack yes you're right. I have edited my code.

Comment: @Jack what is (date_diff) ??

Comment: @ibobo `date_diff` is the alias for the column. You can get the date difference value with `echo $row['date_diff']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attching any variables to string then you need to concatinate them using dot and oder by will come after where condition and inside $_SESSION you missed quotes

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID='".$_SESSION['email']."' ORDER_BY date, time";
```

Comment: Your code, as with all the other answers, contains an SQL injection vulnerability. Don't assume `$_SESSION['email']` is secured just because it came from the database. The user is the one who initially input it.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving latest date from database please try executing following sql query

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[email])."' ORDER_BY date,time desc limit 1";
```

Comment: and what format should i store in the date and time columns ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

you forgot ` here around date. date is reserved word in mysql,

if you want to use it as column name place ` around it.

#### EDIT

also you have extra space remove it

```
$note = "SELECT * FROM notify WHERE seeker='".$_SESSION['email']. "' 
AND donor='".$email."' ORDER_BY `date` LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: i added ` ` around date, also no result :(

Comment: @ibobo you have extra space here `' ".$_SESSION['email']. " '`. see edited query.

Comment: i added then in purpose for making the code here in stackoverflow clear ,, i will remove them

Answer (score 0):

have you try to order by desc? as shown bellow:

```
$note = "SELECT * FROM notify 
           WHERE
           seeker=' ".$_SESSION['email']. " ' 
           AND
           donor=' ".$email." ' ORDER_BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: i did, no result shown :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve latest date you need to sort field for date in descending order

```
  $note = "SELECT * FROM notify WHERE seeker=' ".$_SESSION['email']. " ' AND donor=' ".$email." ' ORDER_BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
```